# Schema Generation

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to generate Schema with 90000 tables from Generate Script option but after sometime it returns error. DB size 600 GB. What's the other way around?

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptPub‌​lishException:
>   An error occurred while scripting the objects. --->
>   System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput(Uri baseUri, String
>   baseUriStr, Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, Encoding
>   encoding) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, Stream
>   input, XmlNameTable nt) at System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor(Stream
>   input) at

Comment: Possible answer here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75326/management-studio-system-outofmemoryexception

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

**Visual Studio**

- Create a new Sql Server project.
- Right click on the project and select ***Import - Database***

You'll get an structure like this:

[image]

Third party tools like:

**ApexSQL**

- By using [ApexSQL Script](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_script.aspx)

> Script SQL objects and data into scripts and deployment packages

**DbSchema**

I've not tested it.

http://www.dbschema.com/

**SQL Power architect**

Has a [community edition](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **SSIS** which is the simplest method.

Or generate the script for each table in a separate **.sql** file. then create a batch file to execute one by one.

Comment: Another option is using `Smo Scripter` via Powershell.