# How to optimize stored procedure so it won't end with "Out of memory exception"

Tags: sql-server, optimization, stored-procedures, transaction

I have created a stored procedure that check against 2 and then delete from the 3. 
When I execute the stored procedure on Management Studio I get the exception as mentioned in this question: [StackExchange Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75326/management-studio-system-outofmemoryexception)
However what my question is how to optimize the SP so it will not take that long time to run?
My code is as following:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Clean] ( 
 @Deletion date
  ) AS
   BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION Cleaning
DECLARE @id int
Declare @ErrorCode int =1


 DECLARE cursorE CURSOR local fast_forward FOR
        select distinct m.ID
        from Member m
        left join (
            select *, row_number() over (PARTITION BY rid order by ceid 
desc) as rn
            from TypeA
        ) x on m.ID = x.ID and x.rn = 1
        where (
            (x.ceid is null and m.LastChangedDateTime < @Deletion) 
            or x.Resignation < @Deletion
        )                   

    OPEN cursorE
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorE INTO @erID

     WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )  
  DELETE FROM Errn WHERE erid = @id
  FETCH NEXT FROM cursorE INTO @rID
  COMMIT TRANSACTION Cleaning
  RETURN 1
  END         
 CLOSE cursorE
DEALLOCATE cursorE
ERRORHANDLER:
-- Rollback the transaction if there were any errors
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Cleaning
 RETURN @ErrorCode
```

GO

Comment: Try adding a `BEGIN` after the `WHILE` and an `END` after the `FETCH`. I expect your proc would then run faster by avoiding the infinite loop. Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` might avoid the out of memory issue with SSMS. A better solution is a set-based delete query instead of cursor.

Comment: You could just do this as a single delete statement. Is there a reason why you don’t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single statement.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM 
    Errn 
WHERE 
    erid IN (
             select 
                 distinct m.ID
             from 
                 Member m
             left join 
                 (select 
                      *, row_number() over (PARTITION BY rid order by ceid desc) as rn
                  from TypeA) x 
                 on m.ID = x.ID and x.rn = 1
             where 
                 (
                     (x.ceid is null and m.LastChangedDateTime < @Deletion) 
                     or 
                     x.Resignation < @Deletion
                 );

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    RAISERROR('ERR MSG', 16 1);

END CATCH
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. So what you suggest is to do the delete inside the transaction? and drop the While loop? I also need the error handler to check if the commit in case something goes wrong. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Mindan, you don't need an explict transaction with a single delete statement since it will run in an all-or-none autocommit transaction. No need for the try/catch block with a single statement either.

Comment: @DanGuzman it is just an example