# SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition using more than 64GB of memory, why and how?

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory

I put SQL Server 2012 Standard on a virtual machine (VMWare) which has roughly 98GB of Memory.

Now I checked the query below how much memory is taken by SQL Server.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)
```

And see that he ate already 81GB of the memory and the max Memory is set to ~90GB.

Using:

```
select (physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024)Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB,      
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024 )Locked_pages_used_Sqlserver_MB, 
(total_virtual_address_space_kb/1024 ) VAS from sys. dm_os_process_memory
```

SQL Server 2012 Standard should support only 64GB of memory.

Why does my SQL Server eat more than he can? Or is the info incorrect?

Any idea? Is that related to a virtual machine using virtual memory?

I don't know if balloon driver is activated on VM Host...

If you need any more info I will add it.

Comment: Stop looking at Task Manager. Look at the DMVs, DBCC MEMORYSTATUS, and sysinternals tools...

Comment: Hey Aaron, thank you first of all. even from sys.dm_os_performance_counters I get 83346104 KB ~ 79 GB.

Comment: What is output of select
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024)Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB,
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024 )Locked_pages_used_Sqlserver_MB,
(total_virtual_address_space_kb/1024 ) VAS
from sys. dm_os_process_memory

Comment: @AaronBertrand I dont think its duplicate because old link is for SQL Server 2005. Lot of changes happened in 2012 and many counters deprecated I guess answer for this could be different. Query I posted will give correct value of memory utilized target server or total server memory will not

Comment: @Shanky the answer didn't deal with just SQL Server 2005, though, did it? The question is the same - how much memory is SQL Server using. We don't need a different copy of the question for every version of SQL Server.

Comment: But I am still curious why OP thinks SQL Server is using more memory than the limit. Even if he is looking at task manager which shows working set it should not be in any case greater than 64 ? This is reason I asked him to give output of DMV

Comment: Even sys.dm_os_performance_counters says SQL Server uses 79GB, my question is NOT how to query the system for memory usage.

Comment: Perfmon counter would not track accurate SQL server consumption. They might be very near, that is why I asked you to post output of query.The result of `Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB` is what is SQL Server actually using in total

Comment: 81.892MB, so still above 64GB.

Comment: Is it 81G or 81mb? The output of query is in mb

Comment: 81GB I just placed the dot for a better view.

Comment: Thanks I might know the answer please note that 64 G limitation is JUST for Database engine if you are using SSIS,SSRS or SSAS memory utilisation can go high because other services would use memory

Comment: ok, that's what I thought as well. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 64GB limit (and 128GB in 2014) applies only to buffer pool. The KB article "[Memory configuration and sizing considerations in SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16)" says:

> Starting with SQL Server 2012, these memory limits are enforced only for the database cache (buffer pool).

And as we all know, `max server memory` also does not control *all* of SQL Server's memory. The official documentation is in the process of being updated to provide the following guidance on this (this exact wording was provided by Bob Ward):

> The server-level `max server memory` setting controls SQL Server memory allocation, including the buffer pool, compile memory, all caches, qe memory grants, lock manager memory, and clr memory (basically any “clerk” as found in `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks`). Memory for thread stacks, memory heaps, linked server providers other than SQL Server, or any memory allocated by a “non SQL Server” DLL is not controlled by max server memory.

So, it is quite feasible that you will see `sqlservr.exe` use *more* than 64GB of memory if there is significant allocation to anything other than the buffer pool, even in Standard Edition (and more than 1GB even in Express Edition).

If you want to stop SQL Server from using more than 64GB of memory, you'll need to set `max server memory` to something less than 64GB (you may need to experiment here to find the right mix, but understand that the non-buffer pool memory can fluctuate, so you may still see things that venture beyond both the licensing limit and the configured limit).

**Or**, you can just leave it as is, and be thankful that you can use up to 64GB for buffer pool *and* plenty else for other things that might otherwise cut into buffer pool usage if the 64GB limit were an enforced hard cap.

---

You can see how memory is distributed in various ways. Among the memory clerks, you can use:

```
SELECT [type], mem_MB = pages_kb/1024
 FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
 ORDER BY pages_kb DESC;
```

In most cases, the top consumer is going to be `MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL`, but you should see significant volume in `CACHESTORE_*` entries as well. You can group it at a higher level using something like:

```
SELECT [type] = COALESCE(SUBSTRING([type],1,CHARINDEX('_',[type])-1),'-- total'),
  SUM(pages_kb/1024)
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((),SUBSTRING([type],1,CHARINDEX('_',[type])-1));
```

To see how cache/user store memory is distributed:

```
SELECT [type], name, 
 mem_MB = CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,2),pages_kb/1024.0) 
 FROM sys.dm_os_memory_cache_counters
 ORDER BY pages_kb DESC;
```

Currently, on my lowly VM, the query in your question (provided by @Shanky) says that SQL Server is using 2,085 MB of memory (with 2,004 MB locked in memory). However my query above against the memory clerks DMV says that the total memory being used there is only 1,793 MB.

The query in Chris' answer says that the total is 2,054 MB, with a target of 3,072 MB (this is because I have explicitly set `max server memory` to 3,072 MB).

So where is the extra ~200 MB? Who knows. (I can also see this difference if I compare `total server memory` to `Process > sqlservr > Private Bytes` in Performance Monitor.) I could start parsing the output of `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` to try and piece it together (and [Tim Chapman wrote some PowerShell to make that easier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/timchapman/how-to-parse-dbcc-memorystatus-via-powershell)), but is it worth it? Is all memory even reported there? I'm not 100% certain that it is (or that you should use the output at all in a NUMA system), or that any DMV can give a fully accurate picture of all of the memory being used by SQL Server. I also don't believe all the memory clerk types are even documented anywhere - so even if that gave a complete picture, you might still be scratching your head over what the results really mean.

Task Manager, meanwhile, says `sqlservr.exe` is only using 42 MB. **Whatever you do, *please* stop using Task Manager. For anything, really.** I know you have removed this detail from your question in your most recent edit, but I can't stress enough how useless it is for showing SQL Server memory usage.

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron for re-opening the question and answering in detail.Looking forward to hear your speach at #sqlbits in Lodon. ;)

Comment: Thanks for opening it again. This was precisely my point and I was thinking same that Limit is just for SQL Server database engine

Answer (score 3):

Per Aaron Bertrand's answer ([Quick look at how much RAM is allocated to SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/quick-look-at-how-much-ram-is-allocated-to-sql-server)).  Task Manager shouldn't be used to ascertain how much memory SQL is actually using.

I prefer to use the following query (Again, thanks Aaron):

```
SELECT object_name, cntr_value
  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
  WHERE counter_name IN ('Total Server Memory (KB)', 'Target Server Memory (KB)');
```

Alternatively, using `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` will yield this information (as well as a slew of additional information).

Comment: Aaron did not say Perfmon shouldn't be used, `Task Manager` should not be used. I can use Performance Monitor to get the same value as your query is going to.

Comment: I mistyped that.  That should have said Task Manager. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this query, gives me a more accurate total actual memory in use -

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select 
    @@Servername,
    osn.node_state_desc, 
(
select physical_memory_in_use_kb/(1024) as SQLMEMORYINUSE_MB
from sys.dm_os_process_memory
) + (omn.locked_page_allocations_kb / 1024.0 ) as Tot
from sys.dm_os_memory_nodes omn
inner join sys.dm_os_nodes osn on (omn.memory_node_id = osn.memory_node_id)
where osn.node_state_desc <> 'ONLINE DAC'
and osn.node_id = 1
```

I appreciate the post is old, but this may be of use.

I have an instance of 2012 std, which is using some 120Gb ram in total