# SQL Server 2008 R2 Service - large memory consumption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server instance where the service is consuming 173 GB, the max server memory is set at 60 GB. How do I determine where that memory is or if I have a memory leak?

Comment: Also see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/quick-look-at-how-much-ram-is-allocated-to-sql-server

Comment: What is output of  `select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory`